# How to display data from vue javascript to html

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have written few lines of code using javascript in Vue framework. I can not display date on html from var. I used vue-bootstrap for styles. Any suggestion is app?

```
<template>
    <div class="app">
        <b-form-datepicker id="datepicker" class="weekpicker" placeholder="Select a week" local="en"></b-form-datepicker>
    <div class="w-75 p-3 mb-1 text-light">
        <b-form-select class="weekpicker" onfocus="myFunction()">
            <b-form-select-option  hidden value="">Select a week</b-form-select-option>
            <b-form-select-option  id="mydate"  value="">{{ myFunction() }}</b-form-select-option>
            <b-form-select-option  type="date"  value=""></b-form-select-option>
            <b-form-select-option  type="date"  value=""></b-form-select-option>
        </b-form-select>

    </div>
        <button><span>Submit</span></button>
    </div>
</template>


<script>


export default {
  name: 'TS_home',
  data() {
    return {
    };
  },
    methods: {
      myFunction() {
          let x = new Date();
          let current_date = x.toDateString();
          x.setDate(x.getDate() + 7);
          let seventh_date = x.toDateString()
          document.getElementById("mydate").innerHTML = current_date + " - " + seventh_date;
      }
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Don't manipulate the DOM with JS. Use the tools that Vue provides. Set a `data` property  (eg `mydate`) and display it in your template using `{{ mydate }}`

Comment: You should also be using a Vue event handler, ie `@focus="myFunction"`

Comment: When i use @focus placeholder is not showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Phil said since you are using Vue you should define the data property for the date like so:

```
data() {
  return {
    myDate: null
  }
}
```

When it comes to date pickers it is usually `@change` event or `v-model`.

Try:

```
<b-form-datepicker id="datepicker" class="weekpicker" placeholder="Select a week" local="en" @change="myDate=$event"></b-form-datepicker>
```

Then display the property in your HTML template like:

```
{{myDate}}
```

**Another** possibility is to use [vue-bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker) if that is not what you have installed already. You would do it like this:

```
npm install vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker --save
```

then in your component

```
  // Import required dependencies 
  import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

  // Import this component
  import datePicker from 'vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker';
```

then in your data

```
data() {
  return {
    myDate: new Date(),
    options: {
      format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
      useCurrent: false,
    }
  }
}
```

and in your HTML template

```
<date-picker v-model="myDate" :config="options"></date-picker>
```

and to display that date you would again use:

```
{{myDate}}
```

Please refer to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker) for more detailed information.

I hope it helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the data property instead of manipulating the dom

```
data() {
  return {
    myDate: ''
  }
}
```

Inside the function

```
myFunction() {
          let x = new Date();
          let current_date = x.toDateString();
          x.setDate(x.getDate() + 7);
          let seventh_date = x.toDateString()
          this.myDate = current_date + " - " + seventh_date;
      }
```

In the html, use the vue-event handler

```
<b-form-select class="weekpicker" @focus="myFunction()">
```

```
<b-form-select-option  id="mydate"  value="">{{ myDate }}</b-form-select-option>
```

Hope this will help  :)

Comment: Thanks for reply, Nope it is not displaying the date.